# What does LookupAddressForName do and why is it so slow

Tags: c++, windows, performance

We have an application which uses a closed source library. One of our customers complains that the application takes long on startup, and sent us a performance trace (using the microsoft concurrency visualizer).

In this trace, I can see that on startup, about a minute is spent inside ws2_32.dll!LookupAddressForName, called from the third-party dll.

(This is multiple calls, not a single call taking so long, but since the concurrency visualizer uses sampling, not instrumentation, I can't see how long each individual call takes.)

I couldn't find any documentation on LookupAddressForName, but judging from name and context, I assume that it translates a hostname to an ip address, e.g. does a DNS lookup.

I can't reproduce this locally, and I can't install a debugger at the customer.

The customers OS is Windows 7.1 Enterprise, joined to a Domain.

Do you know under which circumstances LookupAddressForName might block multiple seconds?

Comment: DNS timeout is usually 30secs.  So a non-responsive DNS server will block the on the call for multiple seconds.  Also a badly formed name lookup can block as the DNS server tries to find an authoritative DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

A slow network connection is the most common situation. Think a remote branch office connected to head office via a very slow connection.